# xx% of the number of tokens sold went to the liquidity pool for sale

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm creating a token. I want that when selling tokens to the liquidity pool, 2% of the number of tokens sold went to a certain wallet, and 98% of the number of tokens sold went to the liquidity pool for sale. Code snippet:

```
................................
mapping (address => uint256) public balances; // user 
  marketFee = 2;
  marketAdr = 0x1234;
................................
 function _transfer(address from, address to, uint tokens) internal returns (bool) {
    if (to == uniswapV2Pair) {
................................
       marketTokens = marketFee * tokens/ 10**2;
       balances[marketAdr] = balances[marketAdr] + marketTokens;
       balances[from] = balances[from] - tokens;
       sellTokens = tokens - marketTokens;
       balances[to] = sellTokens;
       emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
       return true;
   }
}
...................................
```

I have a question. How can I transfer only 98% of tokens to the liquidity pool and extract the appropriate amount of ETH from it?
Do I need to call swap or add something to the liquidity pool? Guys, tell me, please.

Comment: What does extracting ETH from the liquidity pool mean? You want to take the amount of ether that corresponds to the amount of tokens the pool received and transfer that to some other account?

Comment: Marko Popovic, thanks for the question. I formulated my question incorrectly. I want that when selling tokens to the liquidity pool, 2% of the number of tokens sold go to a certain wallet, and 98% of the number of tokens sold go to the liquidity pool. I wanted to find out if I was doing it right. And whether something else needs to be done.

Comment: Well this question depends on you exact requirements. At least at a first glance, it looks good. I would suggest you create some tests that test the main use case, as well as corner cases, instead of asking for code review on this site.